# dsPIC33EP512GP502 -> ADPCM?

Tags: pic, dsp, mplabx, tdma

It seems that ADPCM is all but non-existant anymore. But I'd like to use this to compress six high-quality audio channels into a smaller bit-stream with little overhead.

There seems to be a [dsPIC G.726A Speech Encoding/Decoding Library](http://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/product.aspx?product=G.726A%20Speech%20EncodingDecoding) and accompanying [User's Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70665A.pdf), however:

- These files are for 8kHz sample rate; desired is 40kHz.
- I can't find these files anywhere. (And think they were for the old MPLAB.)

This is compounded by the intended function of this dsPIC:

- Acquire six samples from SPI1 device (40kHz rate, 16-bit)
- ADPCM the six samples from 16-bit to 4-bit
- Multiplex these 24 bits into 3 bytes, queue/wait for SPI2
- Send to SPI2 device (both 8MHz SPI)

Even at 64MHz clock, I have no clue as to whether this dsPIC has enough horsepower to accomplish all of this. The user's guide above in table 4-4 reads that the "computational speed [of the] encode function [is] 7MIPS" which is ambiguous for many reasons.

Application note [AN643](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00643c.pdf) shows some generic C code for implementing ADPCM compression, but nothing tailored to dsPIC. The [dsPIC libraries](http://www.microchip.com/doclisting/SoftwareLib.aspx?category=Audio+%26+Speech&title=) for dsPIC33E which are available, are all precompiled for low sample-rate telephony applications.

Can anyone give insight into a direction to proceed? Is this futile with a single dsPIC? Is hacking dsPIC assembler the only way? Is there a better way to approach this application?

Comment: It would help to define ADPCM.  Your question is impossible to answer without having some idea of the computational complexity.  The EP series can run up to 70 MIPS, so I don't know where your 64 MHz clock or 7 MIPS figures came from.  Using canned library code is probably more work than just looking at the spec and writing what you need directly.  Then you have the added advantage of understanding it thoroughly and being able to modify it as needed.  Again, I don't know what ADPCM is, but can it really be that hard?

Comment: By 64MHz I meant 64MIPS, apologies. Adaptive Differential PCM takes advantage of the high correlation between consecutive samples, which enables future sample values to be predicted. Instead of encoding individual samples, ADPCM encodes the difference between a predicted sample and the real sample. This method provides more efficient compression with a reduction in the number of bits per sample, yet preserves the overall quality. 16-bit audio can be reduced to 4-bit with great clarity. AN643 shows the C equivalent for compression and decompression.